# Some error with parse json

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some error when i parse json data. This is json:

```
    [{
    "name": "TqgQdaaqQU",
    "location": "YEyFMkCiAjGRsxa",
    "type_id": 68,
    "gos_prinad_id": 64,
    "disloc_country_id": 95,
    "adm_terr_id": 57,
    "lat": 142.48033105609792,
    "lon": 90.31768510181121,
    "alt": 483,
    "hops": [{
        "hop_type": "KZMzTuUnNw",
        "id_sl_hop": 928,
        "hop_text": "GZOvhipRpTgwPDkeGKrl"
    }]
}]
```

And this is a part of my template. UPD for `<div>` block

```
    <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor='let list of lists'>
          <td>{{ list.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ list.location }}</td>
          <td>{{ list.type_id }}</td>
          <td>смотр.</td>
          <td>{{ list.lat }}</td>
          <td>{{ list.lon }}</td>
          <td>{{ list.alt }}</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td colspan="6"></td>
          <td colspan="2">Страниц: из </td>
          <td colspan="2">Просмотр: из </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <div>
      <br>
      <table>
         <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Тип ХОП</th>
                  <th>Текст ХОП</th>
                  <th>Номер ХОП</th>
               </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let new_var of list.hops">
                <td>{{ new_var.hop_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ new_var.id_sl_hop }}</td>
                <td>{{ new_var.hop_text }}</td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
   </div>
```

with `{{list.name}}` and etc. i have no problem, but with `{{new_var.hop_type}}` i have this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hops' of undefined`, please, help!

Comment: you have wrong implementation of html, list variable's scope is only limited to first tr tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because variable `list` is a local template variable and it only exists in your first `<tr>` tag thanks to keyword `let`. This is solution for your problem:

```
<table>
<tbody *ngFor='let list of lists'>
   <tr>
      <td>{{ list.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ list.location }}</td>
      <td>{{ list.type_id }}</td>
      <td>смотр.</td>
      <td>{{ list.lat }}</td>
      <td>{{ list.lon }}</td>
      <td>{{ list.alt }}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="6"></td>
      <td colspan="2">Страниц: из </td>
      <td colspan="2">Просмотр: из </td>
   </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let new_var of list.hops">
      <td>{{ new_var.hop_type }}</td>
      <td>{{ new_var.id_sl_hop }}</td>
      <td>{{ new_var.hop_text }}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This way, variable `list` can be accessed in your second `*ngFor` iteration and you'll be able to display all your data properly.

Comment: Thanks, a lot! And if i want to create `*ngFor` directive in new div block, after table, how syntax this?

Comment: @EduardArevshatyan You can use `*ngFor` directive as many times as you want, but you won't be able to access local template variables `list` and `new_var` outside of table.

Comment: i update my code with `<div>` block, please, say, what wrong